# How do I find the user that was specified on a drive mapping?

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

I'm running Windows 7, and I have various network drives that were previously mapped.
I want to check which credentials were specified at the point that the mapping was created.
How can I see this information?

Comment: I doubt you will find that information, but if it is anywhere, check the security log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer Management->Shared Folders->Sessions will show anyone currently connected, along with the username they are connecting with

Comment: I think the OP is talking about disconnected drives.

Comment: If so, then he has to hope the security logs got it... But doubtful. It won't by default

Comment: @Kyle, I'm referring to connected drives

Comment: @Luke, thanks for the answer, it was the reverse of what I needed. It shows who is connected to my shares, I needed to see what user I had connected as to a network share. So I logged on to the server using Remote Desktop, and found my session from there. Thanks!